# how to make one type of another?

Tags: typescript, types

how can I make the values of "Text Block Type" the keys of "IFormats", which may not be

`type TextBlockType = 'markdown' | 'test' | 'presentation';`

```
interface IFormats {
  [index: TextBlockType]: string;
}
```

I did it like this

```
type FormatsType = {
    [key in TextBlockType]: string
}
```

I want to get

```
type FormatsType = {
    markdown?: string
    test?: stirng
    presentation?: string
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```ts
type TextBlockType = 'markdown' | 'test' | 'presentation';

type FormatsType = {
    [key in TextBlockType]?: string
}
```

Alternatively, you can use Record and Partial utility types:

```ts
type FormatsType = Partial<Record<TextBlockType, string>>
```